# Disable GraphQL introspection logging in java application

Tags: java, logging, graphql, introspection, disable

While running any client that connects to my java app with graphQL,
I get all schema being logged, which is quite a mess, and I would like to disable this log entries (request and response) for:

> __schema

and

> __type

I guess sthg like fo JS:
[JS graphQL disable introspection](https://github.com/helfer/graphql-disable-introspection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when using:

`<properties>   <kotlin.version>1.3.10</kotlin.version> </properties>`

and

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
     <artifactId>graphql-java-tools</artifactId>
     <version>5.6.0</version> 
 </dependency>

graphql:   
   tools:
     introspection-enabled: false
```

from: [graphql-java-kickstarter](https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-java-tools)

it should work (according to: [issue-247](https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-spring-boot/issues/247))
rather when no other tools/starter is used

Comment: [https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-spring-boot/blob/master/README.md#basic-settings]